# finite simplicial complex compact

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $K=(V,\Sigma)$ be a finite simplicial complex. I want to show that $|K|$ is compact. I know that $K$ is a sub-simplicial complex of $\Delta^V$ with $|\Delta^V|$ compact. So I think I should show that $|K| \subseteq |\Delta^V|$ is closed and therefore compact. But I have trouble understanding how a sub-simplicial complex translates into a sub-space.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to express $|K|$ as a quotient space of a disjoint union of simplices? Then the compactness would follow from the fact that a finite disjoint union of simplices is compact together with the fact that the continuous image of a compact space is compact.

Comment: I know that $K$ can be expressed this way. But I do not know that finite disjoint union of simplices is compact together.

Comment: Well, a single simplex is compact, and if a space $X$ is the union of finitely many compact subspaces, then $X$ is compact too. The proof for the later statement is easy.

Comment: If $V$ was infinite, then not every simplex would necessarily be compact, right?

Comment: But a simplex has, by definition, only finitely many vertices.

Comment: Ah, alright, I think I get it now. Thanks